# How to use vimium to select text from a page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, vi, macvim, vimium

## Background

I'm a religious fanatical devoted believer of [vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en).  It speeds up my internet usage like nothing else. I'm also (naturally) a heavy user of vim itself.

## Question

How can I actually select a certain text in a screen using vimium without using a mouse? For example let's say I got this email on the page `mail@mail.com`. Is there a way i can for example search for that term first of all, then using vimium highlight the rest of the term as if I'm using a cursor?

so a more practical example
`mailto@verycomplicatedandlonganduglydomainthatiwontsearachfor.com`
so i simply search for `mailto`, then as that gets highlighted, i can move the cursor to the end of the term or at least highlight one word at a time. Idas?

Answer (score 35):

If you specifically want to search for `mailto` but then select `verycomplicatedandlong...` i.e. search one string in order to find the second (unknown) string, which you then want to select.

<kbd>/</kbd>  mailto  <kbd>Enter</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd>  veryl  <kbd>Enter</kbd>   <kbd>v</kbd>  <kbd>ww</kbd>   <kbd>y</kbd>

**Shortcut explanation.**
 <kbd>/</kbd>  - Enter search mode.
mailto - Literal search string.
 <kbd>Enter</kbd>  - Normal mode.
 <kbd>/</kbd>  - Now that you know your second search string, enter search mode again.
veryl - Literal search string.
 <kbd>Enter</kbd>  - Enter normal mode (optionally you can use <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to find other instances of the same search string).
 <kbd>v</kbd>  - Enter visual mode.
 <kbd>ww</kbd>  - Select two words (domain and TLD) or use <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to select one character at a time.
 <kbd>y</kbd>  - yank (copy).

Comment: So basically, the answer is visual mode, plus `vi`-like word navigation shortcuts.

Comment: This just changed my life... I used it to copy some summary text from a page, which I then pasted into a new bookmark.  Now when I press "b", I can quick-find using bits of that summary text!

Comment: https://itectec.com/superuser/google-chrome-how-to-use-vimium-to-select-text-from-a-page/ Is this answer from here?

Comment: @jasonleonhard this looks like a dodgy site that will display other sites content without permission or reference just for their own benefit.

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to check bc it looks very similar to this post.

Comment: I'm wondering if we can copy text without scrolling... I'm a bit annoyed by the fact that when the search mode finds more hits it will jump to the other ones where you're not even interested in.

Comment: After highlighting and yanking the text is still highlighted. How to unselect?

Comment: @Kennet Celeste Try forward slash and then Esc.

Answer (score 4):

### **You might find the directions for Vimium Visual Mode helpful:**

https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Visual-Mode

They also include Caret Mode. They are the same as vim in general, though perhaps not as full featured or customizable, as you would expect.

Answer (score 3):

As a slight improvement on Filip's answer, I would suggest searching for mailto like he suggested, but then going into visual mode right away, then using w or e to select text to the end of the address and then using ow to switch to the marker at the beginning of the word and moving it forward. So the full command would be: <kbd>/</kbd> mailto <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ee</kbd> <kbd>ow</kbd>